# Unable to receive form information with Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to receive a variable from a form however I used try and except but found nothing was being received. Here is my code:

**Python with Flask:**

```
@app.route('/topic/<topic>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def questions(topic):
    g.db = connectDB()
    query = 'SELECT question, questionNumber FROM questions WHERE topic=\"' + topic + '\"'
    try:
        thisQuestion = request.form['thisQuestion'] + 1
        print 'try'
    except:
        thisQuestion = 0
        print 'except'
    cur = g.db.execute(query)
    questions = [dict(question=row[0], questionNumber=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    question = questions[thisQuestion]['question']
    questionNumber = questions[thisQuestion]['questionNumber']
    g.db.close()
    return render_template('topic.html', topic=topic, subject='chemistry', question=question, qn=questionNumber, thisQuestion=thisQuestion)
```

**HTML form**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('questions', topic=topic, thisQuestion=thisQuestion) }}">
```

Want I want to happen is for the thisQuestion variable is start on 0 with every session but increase its value by 1 every time the form is submitted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because one of the following things:

- You didn't specified `name` tag to you input
- You missed spelled the `name` tag (case sensitive?)
- You have some security plugins that blocks the requests(but this is less common)

Comment: I want it to send the thisQuestion variable without any input. Can I do this? I tried putting a text input with the value and name set to 'thisQuestion' but that doesn't seem to work either. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: just add a hidden input with  `name="thisQuestion" value=1`

Comment: That's what I did, it works well, thanks for the reply anyway.